# LWUIT tactile device issue

Tags: events, java-me, lwuit

I need to capture the event that an app throws when you click on the screen, on a list. When I click on the screen, `actionPerformeed(ActionEvent e)` returns `-1`, I suppose that it is the default event.

In non-touch devices, the launched event by pressing the central button is `Canvas.FIRE`, why not in tactile devices?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actionEvent source argument will be from the list. Action events are designed to **encapsulate** the trigger for the action (e.g. key/touch) since that is irrelevant. There is no need to distinguish the trigger since you can always extract the lists selected item and use that.

There are use cases where one would like to know the location touched within the cell renderer but that is a special case unrelated to the question.

Comment: don't you think it could be useful to have that information? I mean, I miss a `getEventType()` method on the ActionEvent, does it make any sense to you?

Comment: You can check the keyCode against -1 but generally you need to distinguish between event types. E.g. if you add an actionListener to a button you are observing a button press/release which might be triggered by **anything** hence it makes no sense to get an event type. However, if you add a specific action listener to keys or pointer events (which you can do on the form) then you know the source event type in advance.